# Gem::ConflictError while running Rspec test cases

Tags: ruby, error-handling, rubygems

This question and answer might be simple however I thought it would be worth sharing.

I cloned the github repository https://github.com/mikel/mail.git and browsing the specs.

I just thought of running the specs inside the application so ran the command "rspec".

**Error description**

```
athi@localhost mail (master) $ rspec
Running Specs under Ruby Version 2.1.5
/Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2104:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rspec-3.3.0, because rspec-core-3.4.0 conflicts with rspec-core (~> 3.3.0) (Gem::ConflictError)
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from /Users/athi/Documents/apps/github/mail/spec/spec_helper.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/athi/Documents/apps/github/mail/spec/mail/attachments_list_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rspec-core-3.4.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/athi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little search I found that the "bundle" is not initialised for this repository and the Gemfile.lock is missing.

So I just ran

> bundle install

and it worked.

It installed the necessary gems and then I was able to run the specs properly.